# Why the lower the frequency I send, the easier it is to lose packets？

Tags: sockets, udp

I'm exploring the effect of sending frequency on packet loss rate (with udp protocol).

I sent 1000 packets with a length of 10,000 bytes, and the interval between each packet was `1ms`. The result showed that the packet loss rate was 10%~20%. However, when I increased the interval to `10ms`, I thought the server had more time to process the cache, but the results showed that the packet loss rate reached a surprising 40%~50%.

I repeated many times and found that this phenomenon can be reproduced, so rule out the accidental situation.

Some phenomena that may help and other known conditions:

1. When the time interval is 1ms, although the packet loss rate is very low, a very high (close to 80%) packet loss occurs occasionally.
2. The distance between the client and the server is about 1200 km

here is a part of my code, which `client` is a socket

```py
msg = 't' * 10000
interval = 0.01 # or 0.001
for i in range(0, 1000):
    sleep(interval)
    self.client.sendto(msg.encode(), addr)
```

Comment: *"more time to process the cache..."* - which cache? Also, did you only increase the interval or did you increase the length too so that you theoretically reach the same bandwidth? And please note that a message size of 10.000 for UDP is very big already and that you loose the whole message if only a single fragment (size about 1500 bytes with Ethernet) of the message is lost.

Comment: Sry.. @SteffenUllrich  I'm just new about it. In my opinion, it has nothing to do with bandwidth because it is same for both ```1ms``` and ```10ms```. For cache part, it was a guess and I'm not sure about it. I added my code to the description, that might help.

Comment: bandwidth is just bytes transferred over time. so if you're sending the same sized message at 10x the speed then your bandwidth is 10x greater.  you could maybe watch with something like tcpdump/wireshark to see what's going on at the packet level, but doubt this would help much. I'd suggest sending smaller messages (check out fragmentation and MTUs) as well as incorporating some way of checking for/handling dropped packets (or just use TCP)